# Xgboost dump and load issues

Tags: python, pickle, xgboost

I trained my xgboost pipeline model on amazon sagemaker and save the file locally:

```py
pickle.dump(model, open(file_name, "wb"))
```

Then moving to local computer to use model in inference mode:

```py
pickle.load(open(file_name, "rb"))

XGBoostError: [11:45:49] ../src/common/json.cc:458: Expecting: """, got: "76 ", around character position: 1
    {L\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ^~~~~~~~~
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) 1   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258a9a54 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 116
  [bt] (1) 2   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258d69be xgboost::JsonReader::Error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) const + 1054
  [bt] (2) 3   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258d7427 xgboost::JsonReader::Expect(char, char) + 279
  [bt] (3) 4   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258d7bfb xgboost::JsonReader::ParseObject() + 331
  [bt] (4) 5   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258d6467 xgboost::JsonReader::Parse() + 439
  [bt] (5) 6   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258dbfbe xgboost::Json::Load(xgboost::StringView) + 62
  [bt] (6) 7   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000000125960b93 xgboost::LearnerIO::Load(dmlc::Stream*) + 435
  [bt] (7) 8   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001258b510f XGBoosterUnserializeFromBuffer + 159
  [bt] (8) 9   libffi.7.dylib                      0x000000010f72bead ffi_call_unix64 + 85
```

used package version on sagemaker: `xgboost==1.6.1`

Comment: Did you solved? I have same problem...

Comment: Also having the same issue. Writing this to see if there's an update to solution

Comment: Still no update :(

Answer (score 3):

Update xgboost to 1.7.1 and it will solve the problem.

This usually happens when you are loading a model generated in newer version XGBoost package. The reason is that newer version replace 'True' and 'False' with 1 and 0 when it produces trees. When old version XGBoost is trying to load the model, it does not understand what 1 or 0 stands for.

Comment: Updating is a very vague suggestion. Do you know why this particular version would work for the op?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas just updated the answer. Hope it helps